# browser shots wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins

One of my users asked if there was a plugin to take automatically a screenshot from a submitted website url. He also asked if there was a wordpress plugin for this.

can anyone tell me if such a plugin exist for wordpress or if it's possible with php, ajax or any other language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you can use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seekxl-snapr/ this plug-in will show a thumbnail of the url as the mouse over.

There are other plug-ins that uses websnapr[dot]com to create the images as well.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't know of any Wordpress plugins that take screenshots of a submitted website url, however there is a very nice service at http://browsershots.org/ that might be what you're looking for.  Browsershots will render screenshots in almost any combination of browser and OS you could ever want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble with this for a while, it's so hard to get an accurate high quality screenshot generated. I've just released a stable plugin for handling this, it makes the process of automatically generating website screenshots in WordPress dead simple with a simple shortcode:

```
[browser-shot url="http://link-to-website" width="600"]
```

For more info checkout the official plugin page: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/browser-shots/

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you want this. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmp/

> This plugin creates a website screenshot using only a website URL and
>   save into your own wordpress media library.
>
> After creating the image, wordpress will prompt you either to "insert
>   into post" or "change attributes" just like after you upload an image.
>   Renaming is available.